# Looking for the conventions for EONIA swaps used to define EONIA swap rates

Tags: fixed-income, yield-curve

I'm trying to recreate some historical curves using EONIA swap rates. Unfortunately I can't find a concrete specification for the swaps. Without knowing if there are intermediate coupon payments, I can't accurately bootstrap the curve. I've spent maybe 6/7 hours today looking for these so any help from memory or otherwise would be much appreciated.

This is the index whose values I'm trying to use: http://www.emmi-benchmarks.eu/eoniaswap-org/eoniaswap-rates.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

EONIA swaps stopped trading some time in 2014. Since it stopped trading, it does not make sense to remember when it stopped trading :).

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Any links or more information regarding why it is stopped trading etc. will be more helpful.

Comment: I know they stopped publishing the index because of dwindling membership. Why it dwindled I don't know...